# How to hide one item on clicking another item in spinner

Tags: android, textview, hide, spinner

friends here is the code
when i am clicking on amazon it is appearing but when i m clicking on snap-deal the amazon is also displaying

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
    Spinner `sp`;
    TextView tv,tv1,tv2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);`enter code here`
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        String items[]={"amazon","flipkart","snapdeal"};
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(Sample.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
        sp.setAdapter(aa);
        sp.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        if(tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    case 1:
                    {
                        if(tv1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                            tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: TextView variables

Comment: in case 0: make tv visible and others invisible same for case 2 tv1 visible other invisible

Comment: I already try that but it's not working frd

Comment: add your updated code

Comment: case 0:{ if(tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) tv. setVisibility(View.gone); else   tv.setVisiblity(view.INVISIBLE)}

Comment: why you have added if

Comment: To check the condition if tv is visible then tv1 show be in invisible and also tv1 will check if tv is visible tv1 should be invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution ... Have single textView and update the text for this textView.

```
String textSelected = "Select from the drop down";



sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        textSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        textView.setText(textSelected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```